# Load customer header.css AFTER theme's style.css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've got the following PHP code at the bottom of my functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style("header", get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/header.css",  25);
```

It loads the CSS, but it is at the very top of the chain.  I want to override a setting in style.css, which in the `wp_head` function gets loaded later.  I've put the priority (as you can see here) to 25, however its not making any difference.

How can I get it load later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the place in your parent theme that enqueues style.css and get the handle for that stylesheet (most likely "style") and use that in the dependencies arg.

```
wp_enqueue_style("header", get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/header.css",  array("style"));
```

This tells WordPress that your stylesheet is depenent on the "Style" stylesheet and will change the load order accordingly

wp_enqueue_style("header", get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/header.css",  25);

Comment: I'm using the BlankSlate theme, to start from scratch.  Would it be in the functions.php file perhaps?

Comment: that's a good place to start, you can also view the source on the front end, and find the stylesheet you want to know the handle of. WordPress will write the handle in the ID if it is properly enqueued. For example: id='main-styles-css'. The -css is automatically appended, so in this case the stylesheet handle would be main-styles